# Writing and loading expression sets to and from csv files

Tags: r, csv, bioconductor

In R, one can write a bioconductor `ExpressionSet` into a csv file using `csv.write`. For example, using the standard [bladderbatch data available as a bioconductor package](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/data/experiment/vignettes/bladderbatch/inst/doc/bladderbatch.pdf) the following code writes a csv file to the current working drectory:

```
library("bladderbatch")
data("bladderdata")
write.csv(bladderEset, "bladderEset.csv")
```

Is there a tool which can read the produced csv file back into R as an `ExpressionSet`?

If not, is there an `ExpressionSet ↔ csv` serialiser/deserialiser, which can both output ExpressionSets as csv files and read csv files as ExpressionSets?

The reason I'm asking is because I need to interact with ExpressionsSets with python and java code, and I can easily work with "csv" files, but not with ".rda", ".CEL" or other binary files.

Comment: Have you considered interfacing r and python using rpy2?

Comment: I need to work with ExpressionSets in both python and java. rpy2 would only solve half of the problem.

Also, I would like the csv files to be at least in some respect human-readable. For example, I'd like to hand-engineer test cases for my python and java code directly in the form of Expression Set csv inputs.

Comment: Have you tried using the `readExpressionSet` function from the `biobase` package?

Comment: Cheers @NathanWerth, I tried and it doesn't work. Please see my reply to the answer of Stedy

Comment: easily work with "csv" files; you mean a dictionary object on the server? I am curious about ExpressionSet!

Comment: No, I mean comma-separated-values. The format is so widespread there are readily available parsers in java, python and other languages.

Comment: @AdamKurkiewicz I see where you are going, but my general opinion(microsoft guy) is to use Func<Expression<T>> in C#/VB so i can query against it using LINQ. I am indeed more curious how python/R can achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

If you just wanted to interact with the data using R and python, consider saving the ExpressionSet as a feather object.

https://github.com/wesm/feather

Comment: Thanks! Is ExpressionSet a dataframe (apologies, my R skills are very rudimentary).

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work:
```Error: `x` must be a data frame```

Comment: An ExpressionSet is a specific class in the Biobase package optimized for storing gene expression data. It's main parts are a matrix with the expression values, a data frame for feature annotation and a data frame for sample annotation. The advantage of this structure is that you keep data and annotation together in a single object.

Comment: You are correct. Feather requires data frames as input, not arbitrary R objects. So this won't help you, sorry ...

Comment: Thanks, it was a useful suggestion though!

Comment: Maybe store the matrix and the data.frame in two separate feather files?

Comment: @F.Privé Thanks, that would work. Do you have an example R code doing this in both ways, i.e. serialisation and deserialisation?

Comment: @AdamKurkiewicz Maybe [this](https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/03/29/feather/).

Answer (score 1):

The comment from @Nathan Werth is what I think you are looking for. By calling `readExpressionSet` you can easily read in a CSV file as an `ExpressionSet`.

First, write out the CSV file as your initial code:

```
library("bladderbatch")
data("bladderdata")
write.csv(bladderEset, "bladderEset.csv")
```

Then read it back in:

```
temp <- Biobase::readExpressionSet("bladderEset.csv")
> class(temp)
[1] "ExpressionSet"
attr(,"package")
[1] "Biobase"
```

Comment: Thanks @Stedy, this would be indeed what I'm looking after, except is doesn't seem to work.
`bladderEset` has 22283 features and 57 samples, which makes sense, as the number of features corresponds to the number of human genes and the number of samples corresponds to the number of patients.
Alas, `test` has 57 features and 0 samples, which suggests that something went wrong during deserialization. Ideally what I would expect is `bladderEset == test`, but it doesn't look like ExpressionSet supports equality checks. Even if it did though, the check wouldn't pass due to wrong dimensions.

Comment: What we really need to make it work is a `Biobase::writeExpressionSet`, which doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: @AdamKurkiewicz I agree! My next suggestion would be try the Bioconductor forum https://support.bioconductor.org/

Comment: Same problem here! With the above solution a empty eSet will be loaded only.